# Unknown Id.generator not found

Tags: hibernate

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator:   com.agitech.erp.model.act.JournalPeriodIdGenerator
```

Why is hibernate not able to find my IdentifierGenerator, is there an annotation to add? or should I add it during the configuration and how?

```
public class JournalPeriodIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
        private static Long id = new Long(1); // just for test it should return a composite id
        public JournalPeriodIdGenerator(){                  
        }
        @Override
        public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)throws HibernateException {
            //session.list( "select ", queryParameters)
            return id++;
        }       
}
    @Entity
    public class ActEntry extends Record implements Comparable<ActEntry>,Serializable {                 @GeneratedValue(generator="com.agitech.erp.model.act.JournalPeriodIdGenerator")
        @EmbeddedId
        private JournalPeriodId codeId;
        public JournalPeriodId getCodeId() {
            return codeId;
        }
        public void setCodeId(JournalPeriodId codeId) {
            this.codeId = codeId;
        }   
    }
```

following JB Nizet help, I also try (which fails too with same exception )

```
@GenericGenerator(name="JournalPeriodIdGenerator", strategy="increment")
public class JournalPeriodIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
....
}
@Entity
public class ActEntry extends Record implements Comparable<ActEntry>,Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @GeneratedValue(generator="JournalPeriodIdGenerator")
    @EmbeddedId
    private JournalPeriodId codeId;
}
```

Following the second suggestion I try :

```
@Entity
public class ActEntry extends Record implements Comparable<ActEntry>,Serializable {
    @GenericGenerator(name="JournalPeriodIdGenerator", strategy="jrn_increment")
    public class JournalPeriodIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
         .....      
    }
    @GeneratedValue(generator="JournalPeriodIdGenerator")
    @EmbeddedId
    private JournalPeriodId codeId;
...
}
```

another test

```
@Entity
public class ActEntry extends Record implements Comparable<ActEntry>,Serializable {
        @GeneratedValue(generator="JournalPeriodIdGenerator")//with com.agitech.erp.model.act.JournalPeriodIdGenerator not working too
        @EmbeddedId
        private JournalPeriodId codeId;
....
}
@Entity
@GenericGenerator(name="JournalPeriodIdGenerator", strategy="com.agitech.erp.model.act.JournalPeriodIdGenerator")
public class JournalPeriodIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of JB Nizet and folowing this blog http://blog.eyallupu.com/2011/01/hibernatejpa-identity-generators.html

```
    @Entity
    public class ActEntry extends Record implements Comparable<ActEntry>,Serializable { 
// here is the definition that JB Nizet is talking about !
        @GenericGenerator(name="JournalPeriodIdGenerator", 
strategy="com.agitech.erp.model.act.JournalPeriodIdGenerator") 
        @GeneratedValue(generator="JournalPeriodIdGenerator")
        @EmbeddedId
        private JournalPeriodId codeId;
        .....
    }
    @GenericGenerator(name="JournalPeriodIdGenerator", strategy="increment")
    public class JournalPeriodIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc of GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html#generator%28%29) says:

> generator : (Optional) The name of the primary key generator to use as specified in the SequenceGenerator or TableGenerator annotation.

To define your own generator, you would use [GenericGenerator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html), and then reference the name of the GenericGenerator in `GeneratedValue`.

Comment: adding @GenericGenerator(name="JournalPeriodIdGenerator", strategy="increment") to JournalPeriodIdGenerator, and @GeneratedValue(generator="JournalPeriodIdGenerator")@EmbeddedId is not working too !

Comment: You're placing the GenericGenerator annotation to a class Hibernate doesn't know about. Place it on an entity class. And the strategy should be the fully quelified name of the generator class, not "increment". Otherwise, you'll get an increment generator, and not your generator implementation. The javadoc says it: "either a predefined Hibernate strategy or a fully qualified class name". But it seems you never read javadoc. It helps, though.

Comment: i give it a new try, please take a look, the problem is that my english is not very well, that's why i miss things

Comment: doses it mean that i must define the generator in the DB? (i dont think so)

Comment: The **GenericGenerator annotation** should be on an entity class. The class of the generator itself should stay where it was, in its own class. And the strategy attribute should contain the fully qualified name of the class implementing the generator: `com.foo.bar.JournalPeriodIdGenerator`. If you're using Hibernate, you should know what a class name is.

Comment: lol, i honestly try all your advices without sucess, could you please provide the correct code of my exemple